# Converting Raster Data to Polygon data

Tags: raster, gdal, polygon-creation

I am trying to convert a raster data to polygon data. Previously I was using the shapefile.py to create point data on individual lat/lon on the raster. But that will create a Huge data and querying it will be a Big issue.

So, it would be better if I am able to convert the raster data into a polygon data. I was able to find [SAGA](http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html), but it seems that it can [only convert the .grd files](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/saga-gis/wiki/Climbing%20Mount%20St.%20Helens). Is there a way to convert GeoTIFF format or raster datasets in general to Polygon?

**UPDATE: Using gdal_polygonize.py**

I am executing the following line of code,

```
gdal_polygonize.py ~/development/Biodiversity/biodiversity/GeoTIFF/bio11.tif -f "ESRI Shapefile" bio11.shp
```

But I am getting the following error. My gdal version is 1.9.0.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdal_polygonize.py", line 34, in <module>
    import gdal, ogr, osr
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If you are doing land classification with tiffs, check out the link (http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/29570/8104) where there's a method to convert tiffs to polygons using unsupervised maximum likelihood classification.

Comment: thanks @Aaron but i need to work on open source on this project

Comment: is there a way to convert 200 tifs at once?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try [gdal_polygonize.py](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html). E.g., to create a Shapefile `mylayer.shp` from input `myraster.tif`:

```
gdal_polygonize.py myraster.tif mylayer.shp
```

If you need to write to a specific format/driver use (e.g.) `-f PostgreSQL` to write to to a PostGIS database (see the [PostgreSQL / PostGIS driver details for GDAL](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html)):

```
gdal_polygonize.py myraster.tif -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='postgis' user='postgres'" mylayer
```

There are Python bindings underneath to [GDALPolygonize](https://gdal.org/api/gdal_alg.html#_CPPv414GDALPolygonize15GDALRasterBandH15GDALRasterBandH9OGRLayerHiPPc16GDALProgressFuncPv), if you need this tool customized.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Let me try it out. Also, rather than output it as shapefile, can I directly assign this into the PostGIS and access it from the Geoserver.

Comment: @Sam007 yup, PostGIS output works too, see updated

Comment: Got this error why creating the shapefile. Did not add to postgis database. http://dpaste.de/L8tSK/ Is it a problem if the GeoTIFF is in another dir?

Comment: That looks like a distracting error, related to the SWIG bindings used by Python. Which version of GDAL do you have, and how did you install it?

Comment: i have the 1.9 gdal and I installed it using the Synaptic Package Manager. The package manager is also showing that I have 1.7 and 1.8. These might have been installed when i initially installed the OpenGeo Suite. How can I resolve this?

Comment: oh, that's where it get's tricky, and I've been in a similar situation several times myself. However, I'm not sure how to target the correct version.

Comment: which is the version I should be targetting?

Comment: Hmm, not sure, you might need to ask on [gdal-dev](http://lists.osgeo.org/listinfo/gdal-dev) or OpenGeo about your particular setup. I'm not sure how the two interact.

Comment: Hi @Mike, I know this has been a long time but if I wish to install gdal_polygonize on a fresh Ubuntu copy, where should I start? Should I post it as a new question?

Comment: @Sam007 Try `sudo apt-get install python-gdal`, but if that doesn't work, then yes post a new question. I still haven't got around to testing how it works or not with OpenGeo.

Comment: thanks @Mike I am trying it without the OpenGeo. Convert it into shapefile and then host it on GeoServer manually

Comment: just one correction @Mike, I was asked to install `libgdal1-dev` aswell. Not sure if that is a necessity but now I have gdal 1.9.0

Comment: facing some error, any idea where I am going wrong? Updated the question

Comment: @Sam007 : I've never seen an error like that (referring to `libjvm.so`), so I'd ask a new question where you provide more details on your setup and how you installed gdal