# Create shapefiles from SEG-Y files?

Tags: software-recommendations, geology

I am working with seismic data.

Previously we had a tool or a script that could scan these data (SEG-Y) and produce a polygon and shapefile based on the header info from the SEG-Y-files.

This scripting tool came together with a database-platform that was very costly.

So when we decided to change platform we also lost the scanning tool.

Any ideas if this is possible in other software or tools?

Comment: when you say `earlier` do you mean previously.  Are you saying that you once had a tool that could do this (what was it), but now you don't have access to it?  when you say `or any other way`  do you mean some other piece of software, or some other way of working with the data.  can you [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/215021/edit) your question to add clarity on these points.

Comment: I mean previously. The tool was a script created specific for us, but it came along with a database-package so it was very costly. So when we decided to change the database platform we lost the script. Any other means, other ways to produce shapefiles from SEG-Y files. Other software or methods.

Comment: could you edit the question adding this extra information, you shouldn't expect potential answerers to have to trawl through the comments to get all the details.

Comment: you could look at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29662/converting-raster-data-to-polygon-data

Answer (score 1):

I just came across Seismic Explorer for ArcGIS which appears to be a 3rd party extension to ArcGIS Desktop that supports SEG-Y format:

> The Geocap Seismic Explorer for ArcGIS is an extension to ArcGIS for
>   Desktop 10 that allows you to manage and visualize seismic data in
>   ArcGIS.
>
> Main features include:
>
> - Read  2D and 3D seismics from original **SEG-Y** files.
> - Visualize seismic data in 3D, including seismic lines and 3D cubes.
> - Visualize navigation lines and outlines in 2D and 3D
> - Read actual survey outlines directly from the original **SEG-Y** files, taking into account zero-traces and missing traces to create an exact
>     outline geometry.
> - Uses Geocap's proprietary brick format to handle seismic 3D cubes of virtually any size
> - Create index files from 3D **SEG-Y** to quickly examine cube contents  while minimizing use of disk space.
> - Extract lines from seismic 3D cubes  based on intersection with arbitrary geometry.
> - Uses standard ArcGIS methods and tools
> - Easy to use interactive seismic navigation. Simply move seismic sections using your mouse or use the seismic toolbar.